# MVC site adding extra quote on links

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, cross-browser

I've got a real simple mvc site that renders fine in Chrome but is having issues in IE.  When I open the Developer Tools Window and look at the console, it shows me this error:

`HTML1423: Malformed start tag. Attributes should be separated by whitespace.`

When I click on that link, it shows this html:

```
<li><a href="/pp/"">HOME</a></li>
```

My code to generate that link is:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("HOME", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

I've even tried:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">HOME</a></li>
```

but the same issue occurs.  I'm not even sure why it's putting that `"/pp/` on there either.  The site is hosted on a sub domain of one of my domains so the link is pp.mydomain.com.

Here's my `RouteCongif` file:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "id",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I originally just had the first route but then added the 2nd one on advice from a friend, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with that. Do you have any routes that you defined yourself?

Comment: @Rob Yes, see updated answer.  I wonder if it's an IE thing then?

Comment: The error is because the href shouldn't contain the second " at the end of the string, but i'm still not sure as to why that's being generated. As an aside, the first route you have there is actually redundant as the second route captures the same urls.

Comment: What happens if you try and render a link to a non-default route? eg. try rendering a link to another actionresult on the default controller.